# Squash or gourd? Monster plant growing from mulch put on empty bed

Tags: identification, vegetables, squash

Please help me identify this monster plant. It grew by itself late July. Yellow flower, somewhat a rounded star shape, indented leaves, some with whitish patches, yellow round smooth "fruit", small 3-4in.

[image: Monster plant]

Comment: I doubt anyone will be able to reliably identify it from anything other than the fruit.

Comment: there is a round yellow fruit there... maybe a pumpkin?

Comment: It looks like it is a vine. If so it's likely to be a pumpkin or gourd.

Comment: Looks like pumpkin to me.

Comment: @rhooligan I think pumpkins typically are considered a vine.

Comment: did the small yellow fruit grow enough for you to identify the plant now? I live in CA and i also have the exact same plant growing in my yard now. no flowers or fruit yet, but lots of lush leaves with white patch/ design.

Answer (score 2):

[Gourds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gourd) generally have a longer vine and smaller leaves than the related [squashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita), *Curcurbita maxima*, pumpkin and hubbard squash, *Curcurbita moschata*, butternut squash and neck pumpkin, and *Curcurbita pepo*, marrows and summer squash. But most cultivated gourds are in the same genus, so the identification of a volunteer like this has to be an educated guess. From the splotches on the leaves, and their appearance in general, I would say probably *c. pepo*.

Answer (score -3):

Definitely Pumpkin. But it is also known as Winter squash. It is known as [Curcubita](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita), botanically. [Ash gourd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ash_gourd) is different from this.

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining **why** you believe it's a pumpkin as opposed to another related species.

Comment: Pumpkin and Winter Squash are related, but two different plants.